# Configure DNS Transfer Zone with multiple Secondary servers using Powershell Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone cmdlet

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server-2019

I am in the process of trying to write a script, using the PowerShell DNS cmdlets, to create multiple DNS zones in a NON-AD Wintel DNS environment where I need to configure multiple Zone Transfer servers and Notify Servers on each zone, and I am passing this information into the script from a CSV file, where the list of secondary servers is in a single cell/field that are comma delimited.
Below is an example of the CSV file and Powershell commands I am trying to use:

CSV FILE contents (file name zones.csv)

> DNSServerName,ZoneName,SecondaryServers,NotifyServers
> DNSServer1.example,firstexample.com,"172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5","172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5"
> DNSServer1.example,secondexample.com,"172.16.0.6,172.16.0.10","172.16.0.6,172.16.0.10"
> <

Powershell DNS Command

```
$RecordUpdates = Import-CSV "D:\zones.csv"
foreach ($Record in $recordsUpdates) {
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name $Record.ZoneName -ZoneFile "$($Record.ZoneName).dns" -ComputerName $Record.ServerName -Confirm:$False -PassThru
Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name $Record.ZoneName -ComputerName $Record.ServerName -SecureSecondaries TransferToSecureServers -SecondaryServers $Record.SecondaryServers -Notify NotifyServers -NotifyServers $Record.NotifyServers -Confirm:$False -PassThru
}
```

I end up with the error such as:

```
Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SecondaryServers'. Cannot convert the varlue "172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5" to type "System.Net.IPAddress[]". Error: "Cannot convert value "172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5" to type "System.Net.IPAddress[]". Error: "An invalid IP Address was specified. ""
```

In essence what the command needs to end up being output as run by Powershell is:

```
Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name firstexample.com -ComputerName DNSServer1.example -SecureSecondaries TransferToSecureServers -SecondaryServers "172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5" -Notify NotifyServers -NotifyServers "172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5" -Confirm:$False -PassThru
```

It seems that the variable value $Record.SecondaryServers (and also $Record.NotifyServers) is interpreted by Powershell as a straight string, not a list as what it would accept if the IPs were manually/explicitly typed into the command.

I've attempted to split the data within the variables to no available (the -split "," command doesn't appear split the data so its readable by cmdlet), I've also attempted to convert the variable values into a new array and then pass that new array, but that also has not worked.

As I have a large set of zones to create with all the data already listed in a large CSV file, some of which will have anything up to 20+ Zone Transfers each, I would prefer to keep the respective Secondary & Notify Server IPs in their respective single CSV fields than have to pass multiple comma separated variables (most of which would end up being blank) to the SecondaryServers & NotifyServers fields.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your IPs with something like this

```
$ip_array = [ipaddress[]] @("192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2")
```

See [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/k1se7l/powershell_newbie_trying_to_make_an_array_of_ip/) for more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just write your command without quotes:

```
Set-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name firstexample.com -ComputerName DNSServer1.example -SecureSecondaries TransferToSecureServers -SecondaryServers 172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5 -Notify NotifyServers -NotifyServers 172.16.0.29,172.16.0.5 -Confirm:$False -PassThru
```